# Adding All Annotated Objects to Collection

Tags: java

I am trying to use the advantage of reflection to add all annotated Objects to a Collection. Frankly, I don't know how to do that. Given that the Objects (or Fields) are annotated with `@DictionaryEntry`, how I can achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Classpath scanning.

Comment: Refer to the Java documentation on annotations.  I'm guessing that there are also many sample code snippets on the internet that show how to do this.  It's one of the standard use cases for annotations.  Spring goes crazy with this idea.

Comment: instance.getClass().getDeclaredFields(), then loop. For each field, field.getDeclaredAnnotations(), check the type, do as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my friend just gave me the answer and I will type it here.
Just iterate the declared fields and filter the annotated with `isAnnotationPresent(DictionaryEntry.class)` and add in the collection with `field.get(this)`.